# Can you use https in HTML doctype declarations?

Tags: doctype

I am wondering if you can use https in HTML doctype declarations?  For example, [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) lists different declarations, all of which have http and not https

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

I have not seen a doctype declaration with https (although, the sample size is small for me).  Is there any reason why this remains as http?  I am assuming the URI gets mapped to https anyways so it's just a cosmetic thing, but why is this still http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use HTML5's `<!DOCTYPE html>` (listed at the w3.org page you linked), but the older declarations are historical curiosities that don't present a security problem. Browsers don't use that `http://...` string that appears in the DOCTYPE tag as a URL to load; it's just a way to declare what standard the author intended to follow.

Comment: I think it's unlikely, but if they did, I think the rest of the answer covers that: the `http://` is not a security issue since it's not used as a URL to load, just a historical indicator of what standard they're trying to follow.